# How to create visualisation of which category has maximum summary value by month in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a visualisation the only shows the category with the highest value each month

I have created a measure to summarise the values for each category but cannot get the chart to just show the category with the highest result for each month - is this possible? The chart filters only allow less than, greater than etc but not maximum [Chart showing all values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cw6B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Create a new measure like:

```
Is Max Priority Weighting for SIR.Area = 
  var meValue = [Priority Weighting max]
  var maxValue = MAXX(ALLSELECTED('Appended Defects'[Safety Inspection Routes.Area]), [Priority Weighting max])
  RETURN IF(meValue = maxValue, 1)
```

Then add this measure to your Visual Filter with "is 1".